# Telling MoveIT a powershell task was successful

Tags: powershell, batch-file

If I am having MoveIT execute a batch file, which then executes a powershell file. Is there a way for powershell to tell moveIT that the entire powershell script was successful without having to create another file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what this MoveIT is, but the Powershell script should be able to do a `exit 0` (for a successful completion) and the batch file can do a `exit %errorlevel%` to communicate success or failure. Using exit codes is the standard way of communicating success or failure while executing scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like MOVEit Central "command line app" script is being used to launch the bat file.  If the bat does nothing else, consider launching the ps script directly, or even better port the ps script to VB and import as a custom script.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is when power shell completes the job, create an acknowledgment in the folder and setup additional condition on moveit to watch the creation of acknowledgment file. I hope MOVEit Central Advance task creation should be more appropriate.